# How do I change obsolete Paypal IPN URL?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Paypal wrote, "Instant Payment Notifications (IPN). IPNs sent to the following URL(s) are failing:" But the URL was an old cart address discontinued and replaced a year ago. How do I switch them to the new address?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where it was set.  Check your PayPal profile under Instant Payment Notification Preferences.  If that's not where it's set then it must be in the NotifyURL parameter of your shopping cart's API requests.